# What's the grammar behind 寝ボケた事(を)言う

Tags: meaning

> 何寝ボケた事言ってんだおめえ

I don't understand the function of 寝ボケた事, is it like "as if you were half asleep"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

寝ぼけた事 means things you say after you 寝ぼけた, like when you just wake up, your mind still wandering in dreamland, in a state of half-asleep, half-awake. A close synonym is 寝言, literally sleep talk. Both can also mean, and often mean, nonsense. Here you don't have to look at 寝ぼけた事 too literally. It is a set phrase. Just know it means nonsense or stupid things.

> 何寝ボケた事言ってんだおめえ
> What the heck are you talking about?